# Overlaying trials in separate files onto one ggplot graph

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to plot one graph with multiple trials (from separate text files). In the below case, I am plotting the "place" variable with the "firing rate" variable, and it works when I use ggplot on its own:

```
a <- read.table("trial1.txt", header = T)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(a, aes(x = place, y = firing_rate)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

But when I try to create a for loop to go through each trial file in the folder and plot it on the same graph, I am having issues. This is what I have so far:

```
 files <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
 for (i in files){
   p <- lapply(i, read.table)
   print(ggplot(p, aes(x = place, y = firing_rate)) + geom_point() + geom_path())
 }
```

It gives me a "Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a list" message. I am a novice in R so I am not sure what to make of that.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You are using a `lapply` loop to read in the files, and this always returns a list, while ggplot needs a data.frame. Could you try `p <- read.table(i)`? Or `p <- read.table(i, header = T)`?

Comment: @teunbrand your suggestion did produce an output but it is not all of the data from the different trials plotted all at once. It just looks different but with the same number of obs.

Comment: @markus I got this message: " Error in x[, c("place", "firing_rate")] : incorrect number of dimensions" but this might be because each trial file has 3 variables but I am just choosing to only look at two (place and firing rate).

Comment: "Error in `[.data.frame`(read.table(x), , c("place", "firing_rate")) : undefined columns selected" Sorry for the struggle, is there any further info I can provide so it does work?

Comment: Do you want all the data from the different trials plotted in one plot all at once? Because in that case and all the columns are the same, you could read all the files in by `mylist <- lapply(setNames(files, files), read.table, header = T)`. Then you can put some ID in a special column with `mylist <- lapply(names(mylist), function(i) {cbind(mylist[[i]], ID = i)})` and subsequently you can combine everything in `mylist` by doing `mydata <- do.call(rbind, mylist)`. But that only works if every file has the same column structure.

Comment: Every file does have the same 3 column structure, but different number of rows. Would your aforementioned method still work?

Comment: In theory yes, be wary that I may have made some typos as I don't actually have the files or data to play around with.

Comment: @teunbrand your method worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general avoiding loops is the best adivce in R. Since you are using `ggplot` you may be interested in using the `map_df` function from tidyverse:

First create a read function and include the filename as a trial lable:

```
readDataFile = function(x){
a <- read.table(x, header = T)
a$trial = x
return(a)
}
```

Next up `map_df`:

```
dataComplete = map_df(files, readDataFile)
```

This runs our little function on each file and combines them all to a single data frame (of course assuming they are compatible in format).

Finally, you can plot almost as before but can distinguish based on the trial variable:

```
ggplot(dataComplete, aes(x = place, y = firing_rate, color=trial, group=trial)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```